# How can I make a sortlist ordered by int value from firebase map data Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
createOnlineLeague() {

  Map<String, dynamic> demoData = {
    "Username": Pedro,
    "Level": 5,
  };
  
  print(demoData);
}
//(Each user upload each Username and Level)

////////////////////////////////////

getData() {
    setState(() {
      CollectionReference collectionReference =
          Firestore.instance.collection('league_online');
      collectionReference.snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
        leagueData = snapshot.documents;
      });
    });
  }
```

I need to sort in a list from the highest to the lowest level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.orderBy("Level", "desc")

```
getData() {
    setState(() {
      CollectionReference collectionReference =
          Firestore.instance.collection('league_online');
      collectionReference.orderBy("Level", "desc").snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
        leagueData = snapshot.documents;
      });
    });
  }
```

Read more on https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Answer (score 0):

getDataLiga() {

```
setState(() {
  CollectionReference collectionReference =
      Firestore.instance.collection('liga_online');
  collectionReference
      .orderBy("Level", descending: true)
      .snapshots()
      .listen((snapshot) {
    leagueData = snapshot.documents;
    
    print(onlineLigaLista);
    print(leagueData[0]['Level']);
    print(leagueData[0]['Username']);
```